# Book with a labyrinth that allows travel to parallel worlds

Tags: story-identification, books

This book featured something called "The Labyrinth" that was a kind of maze that opened into other worlds.

There was one world where all the men were stupid and used as sex objects.

There was a drug that had to be taken regularly by pressing/popping a bead of it onto your skin, and it got into one woman's brain and corrected her eyesight.

I read this book in about 2005.

Does anyone recognise this book?

Comment: "There was one world where all the men were stupid and used as sex objects." Unimaginable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds a little like "The Labyrinth of Dreams" by Jack L Chalker, part of the *[G.O.D. Inc. series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42908-g-o-d-inc)*.

Answer (score 1):

The [*G.O.D Inc. series*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42908-g-o-d-inc) of books, by Jack L. Chalker. It might be the third book in the series (I misremember the name).

Although the men being used as sex objects is not %100, so it might not be what you're looking for.